# ASP.NET JsonResult results in 500 server error when two Json objects contain the same base64 encoded string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I'm returning a serialized list of models to the client. In these models there is a property named "DocumentBody" which is an encoded string of a file (usually an image).

Everything functions as intended, until I upload a duplicate file to the data that is fetched in GetAnnotationsForEntity(). Once I try to return the Json that contains the two objects with the same "DocumentBody" I get a 500 server error in my Chrome console and no additional information. I've stepped through the controller action and no exceptions are thrown.

What is it I don't understand about Json that would make it fail in this instance? As soon as the object with the duplicate "DocumentBody" is removed from the list, everything functions successfully once again. I've experimented with different values for all the other fields with no ill effects. I've also looked at the Json string in a JSON viewer and the structure seems to be as desired as well.

Here is the related code:

Post:

```
axios.post('../GetAnnotationsForEntity', {
            entityType: this.state.entityType,
            entityId: this.props.entityId
        }, { headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' } }).then((result) => {
            if (result.status == 200) {
                  //parse the json data into a list
            }
        }
       });
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult GetAnnotationsForEntity(EntityType entityType, string entityId)
        {
            List<AnnotationModel> annotationsForEntity = new List<AnnotationModel>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityId))
            {
                DynamicsHelper.GetAnnotationsForEntity(entityType, new Guid(entityId))?.ToList()?.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    annotationsForEntity.Add(new AnnotationModel(a.Id, GetOffsetDateTimeForTimeZone(a.ModifiedOn), a.FileName, a.Subject, a.DocumentBody, a.NoteText, GetCulture()));
                });
            }
            string serializedAnnotations = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(annotationsForEntity);
            return Json(serializedAnnotations);
        }
```

AnnotationModel:

```
public class AnnotationModel
    {
        private readonly CultureInfo _cultureInfo;
        private readonly DateTime? _modifiedOn;

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedOn => _modifiedOn.HasValue ? _modifiedOn.Value.ToString(_cultureInfo) : "";
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string DocumentBody { get; set; }
        public string NoteText { get; set; }

        public AnnotationModel(Guid id, DateTime? modifiedOn, string fileName, string subject, string documentBody, string noteText, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            Id = id;
            _modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
            FileName = fileName;
            Subject = subject;
            DocumentBody = documentBody;
            NoteText = noteText;
            _cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
        }
    }
```

Any insight would be appreciated. In the meantime, I have gotten around this issue by not returning Models and Json objects with "DocumentBody" at all, but that's not a solution I'm comfortable with without knowing why it was failing in the first place.

Comment: check response of the request in chrome dev tools - network tab, it should have error message. or check output tab in visual studio

Comment: regarding model - I dont think `CultureInfo` is serializable to json

Comment: Error 500 is just "there was an unhandled exception on the server during processing the request". It's not very useful on its own. Debug menu >> Exceptions Windows >> tick "break on thrown" for "CLR Exceptions", then make a request to your debug server that causes the error. VS should now stop as soon as the error is thrown so you can see what it is.

Comment: Note that for some contexts/scenarios, visual studio might not break on an exception unless the request originates from the browser that appeared when you started debugging..

Comment: The response of the request in dev tools just gives the HTML for the generic "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error" page, talking about NTFS permissions and whatnot. Output in VS (from Debug) doesn't render anything of use.

Comment: Yegor - I don't think it is either, in fact it does not come across in my parsed JSON objects - it merely gets factored in when serializing my models to give the proper culture formatting for ModifiedOn. Only the properties are serialized.

Comment: Caius - I followed your instructions, still no exceptions thrown. (I reproduced the error with the browser window that appeared as well.)